# VS 2013 SDK: Need orientation for Package development

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I need a full working example for **Visual Studio 2013 SDK**, in **C#** or else **VB.Net**, from **MSDN** samples, **SatckOverflow** user(s) or a 3rd party source, that illustrates how to develop a simple package that will integrate a custom menu inside the **Code Editor Window** contextmenu with line separators (groups) and assigned hotkeys, **following good practices** to avoid my current practices.

I'm very frustrated from researching weeks and weeks in **MSDN** without founding any thing that could help me to understand how to do things right, any official or 3rd party example of what I need to do, please be comprehensive.

I've read from begin to end these resources and, I can't find inside orientation or explanations of what I need (a menu inside the code editor contextmenu), however, it helped me to understand other things:

- **[Extending Visual Studio Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx)**
- **[Visual Studio Extensibility Articles](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/)**
- **[Visual Studio 2013 SDK Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VIsual-Studio-2013-SDK-728822a7/)**

---

This below is my actual menu, however, I think from comments of @**Carlos Quintero** that I'm not following good practices because I'm generating the menu and all its buttons at execution time and, If I understood good I should create all these things from an **VSCT** file to be able to assign hotkeys and add line separators and query the commands status:

[image]

---

The VS2013 SDK comes with some project templates, and particullary a **Visual Studio Package** project template which is a project wizard that comes with three templates, any of them demonstrates how to do this, but the command menu template of the wizard is the more approximated thing of what I would like to do, but it is for add a menu under the **Tools** menubar which is obvious I don't pretend to do that, I only would like to add things in the contextmenu of the code editor so I'm using an empty template (which doesn't generates any VSCT file).

The commandmenu package template creates an VSCT file but I don't understand how to create one for my needs in my empty package, or else how to edit the VSCT file that creates the Command Menu package by default to move the command from the **Tools** menu into the code editor contextmenu, I've tested almost all the guids exposed in MSDN.

Also the full SDK package lacks of intellisense support and almost all the SDK members are undocumented in the MSDN (like the guids, which has a name but any description) so it's really a nightmare to understand how to do right things. Sincerelly the articles written by @**Carlos Quintero** are a much better place of documentation than **MSDN**, but it also lacks of important examples such as an example of how to manage a contextmenu.

---

This is the full source of my Package if needed:

- http://www.mediafire.com/download/yezp9qexk8371dr/ElektroSnippet.rar

I'm stuck with much things of that solution because I'm not using an VSCT file which its supposed to help me to realize all the things where I'm stucked, I need to create it from scratch because as said I think that I'm following the wrong practices by creating all controls at execution time instead of from an VSCT file.

I just need to see a working example with VSCT file that creates a similar menu inside the code editor contextmenu, with line separators (groups) and an assigned hotkey, to learn good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio extension development examples:

https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid
https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment/tree/release/CodeAlignment.VisualStudio

There are a lot more open source extensions for visual studio, if you find them, tell me and I'll update this answer so that people can find them on bing or google.

Comment: The second project does not contains any interesting about my needs, but the first project, CodeMaid, helped me a lot to understand things by analyzing the code, thanks for share.